# How do I run a script on each output of Get-ChildObject

Tags: file, powershell, acl

Creating a script to change the ACL on entire directories recursively. The simple script changes the ACL accordingly on one file, however I do not know how to run the script on each file of `Get-ChildItem`

```psh
Get-ChildItem $directory –recurse | % { Write-host $_.FullName }
```

This outputs the appropriate list of directory/file names

```psh
$acl = Get-Acl $file
$permission = "domain/user","FullControl","Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $file
```

Is there a way to set each output of `Get-ChildItem` as `$file`? I was trying to read up on `ForEach-Object` but I haven't been able to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the code you already have in a `foreach` loop. Just get an array of the files by assigning the output of the `Get-ChildItem` call to a variable first:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $directory -recurse

foreach($file in $files) {
  $acl = Get-Acl $file
  $permission = "domain/user","FullControl","Allow"
  $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
  $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
  $acl | Set-Acl $file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
Get-Childitem $directory | ForEach { 
  $file = $_
  $acl = Get-Acl $file
  $permission = "domain/user","FullControl","Allow"
  $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
  $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
  $acl | Set-Acl $file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the current object variable (`$_`):

```psh
Get-ChildItem $directory –Recurse | % {
  $acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_
  $permission = 'domain\user', 'FullControl', 'Allow'
  $accessRule = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
  $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
  Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -LiteralPath $_
}
```

If you want to put the ACL modification into a script and separate it from the `Get-ChildItem` I'd suggest to make the script [process pipelined input](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/10/use-the-pipeline-to-create-robust-powershell-functions.aspx):

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(
    Mandatory=$true,
    ValueFromPipeline=$true,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
  )]
  [IO.FileSystemInfo]$Path
)

Begin {
  $permission = 'domain\user', 'FullControl', 'Allow'
  $accessRule = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
}

Process {
  $acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $Path
  $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
  Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -LiteralPath $Path
}
```

Note, however, that `Get-Acl` cannot modify ACLs where neither your account nor one of your groups is the owner. You can work around this issue by using [`icacls`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx):

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(
    Mandatory=$true,
    ValueFromPipeline=$true,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
  )]
  [IO.FileSystemInfo]$Path
)

Begin {
  $trustee    = 'domain\user'
  $permission = 'F'
}

Process {
  & icacls $Path.FullName "/grant:r" "${trustee}:(CI)(OI)${permission}" | Out-Null
}
```